# 3 divs, 1 Fixed Width, 1 Variable Width(text set), 1 Expanding to fill. Possible?

Tags: css, html

What I'm looking to do is have a fixed width div on the left hand side, a div next to it whose width is set by the text content, and the last div filling up the remaining width.

This is what I have so far:

```
<div style="width: 100%">
  <div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 2px; float: left; width: 100px; ">
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; position: relative; top: -10px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">
    Text
  </div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 2px; float: left; ">
  </div>
</div>
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xjxeu/

I need the example, but with the third div to stretch to the right hand side.

Is this possible without any major 'hack'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: table;`

People can sometimes disagree whether its a hack or not, and look down on tables in general, but it's actually fine. You aren't using tables, tds, or anything, merely making a `div` act like a `table`.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xjxeu/2/)

It is the best, most reliable way to achieve this.

[IE7 and below don't support it.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)